# How strip html out of extjs 4 data store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a bunch of HTML in a database I am interfacing with but don't have access to. I can't control that, or the backend services, but I don't want HTML and Javascript from the database showing up on one of the UI's I'm working on.

The UI I am working on is in EXT 4. What is the best way of stripping out the HTML before it is rendered to the UI? A fairly global EXT solution would be preferred. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is method for this in extjs, as you can see here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-stripTags

```
Ext.util.Format.stripTags("your html")
```

EDIT: If you explain how you use the store to load html (e.g templates), i can help you more.

EDIT: You can override the [field object](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.data.Types) to make it simpler.

```
Ext.data.Types.Html = {
convert: function(v) {
    v += ''; // to make it string
    return Ext.util.Format.stripTags(v);
},
sortType: function(v) {
    return v.substr(10);
},
type: 'html'
};
```

Now you can use `type: 'html'` to achieve strip tags functionality.

Comment: Thanks abeyaz.  I was aware of the stripTags function, and what I want to be able to do is apply that to everything coming in from the back end.  I realize I can go to the model and do a convert on the field to do that, e.g.

    {
        name : 'address1',
        convert : function (v, r) {
            return Ext.utit.Format.stripTags(raw.address.address1);
        }
    }

However, we have dozens of models with tons of fields and I don't want to have to go through and convert each one to do that. Is there a better way to do that on a global basis?